# How to remove main from .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently this code works:

```
RewriteRule ^main/([[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)(/?) /index.php?menu=$1 [L]
```

but I don't want `example.com/main/start`

I want it to be `example.com/start`

I tried to remove only main but I get error then, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your rules to:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+main/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ /index.php?menu=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked mate but it will collapse since I have a code that transfers people to main page incase they enter wrong url.. is it impossible to do this in the single line?

Comment: I'm sorry I just had to copy the last line and it worked. Thanks alot for the help mate :)